# Stop MSVC++ debug errors from blocking the current process?

Tags: windows, unit-testing, visual-c++, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Any failed ASSERT statements on Windows cause the below debug message to appear and freeze the applications execution. I realise this is expected behaviour but it is running periodically on a headless machine so prevent the unit tests from failing, instead waiting on user input indefinitely.

Is there s a registry key or compiler flag I can use to prevent this message box from requesting user input whilst still allowing the test to fail under ASSERT?

**Basically, I want to do this without modifying any code, just changing compiler or Windows options.**

Thanks!

[Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library ASSERT http://img519.imageshack.us/img519/853/snapshotbu1.png](http://img519.imageshack.us/img519/853/snapshotbu1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN about the ASSERT macro:

In an MFC ISAPI application, an assertion in debug mode will bring up a modal dialog box (ASSERT dialog boxes are now modal by default); this will interrupt or hang the execution. To suppress modal assertion dialogs, add the following lines to your project source file (projectname.cpp):

```
// For custom assert and trace handling with WebDbg
#ifdef _DEBUG
CDebugReportHook g_ReportHook;
#endif
```

Once you have done this, you can use the WebDbg tool (WebDbg.exe) to see the assertions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a dialog shown by _CrtDbgReport for reports of type _CRT_ASSERT. With _CrtSetReportHook, you can tailor that behavior for your entire application. (i.e. requires one local change)  In particular, you can continue execution after a failed assertion, thus ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

In a unit-test context, it is often good to convert ASSERTs (actually `_CrtDbgReport` calls) into some exception, typically a std::exception, that contains some informative text.
This tends to wend its way out to the unit test's output log as a fail.
That's just what you want: A failed ASSERT should be a failed unit test.

Do that by throwing in your report-hook function, as specified using: `_CrtSetReportHook()`